# How to change the text color in Python Shell?

Tags: python

Like say, I want to make a simple print statement like:

print("It's so *hot* outside today.")

How could I make "hot" as the color red, in Python Shell?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python it might help you.

Comment: ;-) A real ninja would've searched the already-asked questions before posting a new one. I am kidding, this ninja may be new to SO :-)